Display elements of main script in the node tree
Godot newbie here. I wrote a Godot script to make a scene with a few elements. Is there a way I can visualize the elements in the scene tree and in the 2D editor? What I would like to do is visually check what I defined in the script (collision boxes, etc.). Thanks!

Hiya, any chance we could see your script you're using the generate the scene? Also, is there anything in particular you are trying to achieve with this project? Or just playing around

Not 100% sure what you want to achieve, but you could try using this: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/plugins/running_code_in_the_editor.html
To run code in the editor. I am not sure if this will allow you to spawn entire scenes tbh.

When it comes to scenes being instantiated in code (especially ones intended to be used as templates), I make the scene separately in the editor, make an export variable in the script I want to use the scene in (PackedScene typeset), and assign the variable to the scene. That way, you can see all the details of the scene as you make it, and if you want to see how it looks wherever you're inserting it, you can just add Instantiated Child Scenes into the main scene tree and delete them when you're done testing.
